# each child in an array or iterator should have a unique key prop - but i did define a key prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have definded a key prop. Still react native is throwing this warning:
**each child in an array or iterator should have a unique key prop**

```
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
            >
                {
                    locations.map((location)=> {
                        if (renderArray[wertwert]){
                            let content;
                            if (location.isARealTimeGPS) {
                                content = <View style={styles.marker}/>
                            } else {
                                content = <LocationInfoComponent location={location} handleLocationClick={this.handleLocationClick}
                                                               locations={locations} infoVisible={infoVisible}
                                />
                            }

                            wertwert = wertwert+1;
                            return (
                                <MapView.Marker
                                    key={JSON.stringify(location.latitude)}
                                    coordinate={location}
                                >
                                    {content}
                                </MapView.Marker>
                            )
                        } else {
                            wertwert = wertwert+1;
                        }
                    })
                }
            </MapView>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `JSON.stringify(location.latitude)` is returning a unique value?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you just to use simple map-index instead of anything else:

```
        <MapView>
            {
                locations.map((location, index)=> {
                    ...
                        return (
                            <MapView.Marker
                                key={index}
                                coordinate={location}
                            >
                                {content}
                            </MapView.Marker>
                        )
                })
            }
        </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `JSON.stringify(location.latitude)` returns a unique value.

So an alternative approach would be slight tweak in your iterator function like, using map you can also pass optional argument which will be always unique(The index of the current element being processed in the array.) as it iterates from 0 to what your array's length might be. `arr.map((item,index) => {})`

```
<MapView
            style={styles.map}
        >
            {
                // use optional argument (id) as unique value
                locations.map((location,id)=> {
                    if (renderArray[wertwert]){
                        let content;
                        if (location.isARealTimeGPS) {
                            content = <View style={styles.marker}/>
                        } else {
                            content = <LocationInfoComponent location={location} handleLocationClick={this.handleLocationClick}
                                                           locations={locations} infoVisible={infoVisible}
                            />
                        }

                        wertwert = wertwert+1;
                        return (
                            {/* use "id" as a unique value */}
                            <MapView.Marker
                                key={id}
                                coordinate={location}
                            >
                                {content}
                            </MapView.Marker>
                        )
                    } else {
                        wertwert = wertwert+1;
                    }
                })
            }
        </MapView>
```